# XNA texture coordinates on merged textures

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, texture-mapping

I got a problem with texture coordinates. First I would like to describe what I want to do then I will ask the question.

I want to have a mesh that has more textures using only one big texture. The big texture merges all textures the mesh is using in it. I made a routine that merges textures, that is no problem, but I still have to modify the texture coordinates, so the mesh that now uses only one texture instead of many has everything placed well.

See the picture:

[image]

On the upper left corner I got one of the textures (let's call it A) I merged into a big texture, the right one (B). A's top left is 0,0 and bottom right is 1,1. For easy use let's say that B.width = A.width * 2 and so for the height too. So on B the mini texture (M what is the A originally) bottom-right should be 0.5,0.5.

I got no problems understanding these so far and I hope I understood it ok. But the problem here is, that there are texture coordinates that are:

- above 1
- negative

on the original A. What should these be on M?

Let's say, A has -0.1,0 - is that -0.05,0 on M inside B?

What about those numbers that are outside 0..1 region? Is -3.2,0 on A -1.6 or -3.1 on B? So I clip of the part that is %1 and divide by 2 (because I stated above that width is double) or should I divide the whole number by 2? As far I understand so far, numbers outside this region are about mirroring the texture. How do I manage this, so the output does not contain the orange texture from B?

If my question is not clear enough (I am not much skilled in English), please ask and I will edit/answer, just help me clear my confusion :)

Thanks in advance:
Péter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single texture has coordinates in [0-1,0-1] range

The new texture has coordinates in [0-1,0-1] range

In your new texture composed by four single textures, your algoritm has to translate texture coordinates this way.

- Blue single square texture will have new coordinates in [**0-0.5**,
  0-0.5] range
- Orange single square texture will have new coordinates
  in [**0.5-1**, 0-0.5] range

Comment: I see. What about those coordinates that go outside the ranges? Is there any rule there for the translation? (To make [0-0.5,0-0.5] from a  [0-1,0-1] is just a simple division, but what about if a coordinate in [0-1,0-1] is not in range, but 1.3 or -4.7, etc.?)

Comment: you should read this about [texture mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976075(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx), is about xna 3.1 but the info is valid, although in xna 4.0 you have only three addressing modes wrap, mirror, and clamp. You always have to work in the same way for values inside and outside the range, the matter is what texture addressing mode is being used... if it is not clamp you are in trouble because replicate the wrap and mirror addresing can be not worth